# identity in functional analysis

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

For the past few days I've been studying the topic of functional analysis. I was making an exercise in which I needed to prove the following identity
$$G\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\Big)F(b) = F\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big)[G(x)e^{xb}]|_{x=0},$$
in which we can assume $F$ and $G$ can be expanded in a convergent power series around 0. I started by expanding $F$ and $G$ in convergent power series around $x=0$ but it seemed to me like this did not lead to anything useful. Does anyone have a tip on how to approach this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated :))

Comment: Should the left side be $d/db$ rather than $\partial/\partial b$?

Comment: no this is the exact identity from the exercise

Comment: That would suggest that the left hand side depends on multiple variables, not just the number $b$.

Comment: the question was asked that way since the next part of the exercise wants you to generalise the result for when $b$ and $x$ are vectors in an n-dimensional euclidean space.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't misinterpreting this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ignore convergence and thinking of these as formal power series and operators thereon. Let $$F(y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n y^n$$ and let $$G(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \beta_nx^n.$$  Note that for any $k$, $$\frac{\partial^k}{\partial y^k}F(y)=\sum_{n=k}^\infty \alpha_n \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}y^{n-k}.$$  In particular, $$\frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k}G(x)|_{x=0}=k!\beta_k.\tag{$N$}$$

Also, $$\frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k} G(x)=\sum_{n=k}^\infty \beta_n \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k}.$$   By the general Leibniz rule, $$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}[G(x)e^{xy}]=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\Bigl(\frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k}G(x)\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{\partial^{n-k}}{\partial x^{n-k}}e^{xy}\Bigr) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}y^{n-k}e^{xy}\frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k}G(x).$$ Evaluating this expression at $x=0$ and using $(N)$ gives $$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}[G(x)e^{xy}]|_{x=0}=\sum_{k=0}^n \beta_k \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}y^{n-k}.$$ Therefore \begin{align*}F\Bigl(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Bigr)[G(x)e^{xy}]|_{x=0} & = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n \Bigl[\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}[G(x)e^{xy}]|_{x=0}\Bigr] \\ & = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n \Bigl[\sum_{k=0}^n \beta_k \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}y^{n-k}\Bigr] \\ & = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_n\beta_k \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}y^{n-k} \\ & =\sum_{n,k:k\leqslant n} \alpha_n\beta_k \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}y^{n-k}.\end{align*}

This is the RHS. For the LHS, we have \begin{align*} G\Bigl(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Bigr)F(y) & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \beta_k \Bigl[\frac{\partial^k}{\partial y^k}F(y) \Bigr]\\ & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \beta_k\Bigl[\sum_{n=k}^\infty \alpha_n \cdot \frac{n}{(n-k)!}y^{n-k}\Bigr] \\ & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty \alpha_n\beta_k \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}y^{n-k} \\ & = \sum_{n,k:k\leqslant n} \alpha_n\beta_k \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}y^{n-k}\end{align*}